# how to find the reason that my app does not open in android 8 but opens in android 12 (Kotlin Android Studio)

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, android-version

Hey I work with Kotlin and Android Studio

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!--    <TextView-->
<!--        android:text="Food Lovers"-->
<!--        android:gravity="center"-->
<!--        android:textSize="30sp"-->
<!--        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"-->
<!--        android:textStyle="bold|normal|italic"-->
<!--        android:textColor="@color/white"-->
<!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="161dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/switch_tumbs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/logIn"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_fanum"
                    android:text="@string/log_In"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|normal"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/switch_trcks"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/singUp"
                    android:text="ثبت نام"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_fanum"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/pinkColor"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|normal"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/logInLayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="25dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:hint="شماره تلفن"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/button4"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="#4E4A4A"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
                    app:prefixText="+۹۸"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="phone"
                        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_fanum"
                        />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:hint="رمز عبور"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:textDirection="ltr"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/button4"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="#4E4A4A"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="9dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="9dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="9dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="9dp"
                    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:id="@+id/passwords"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_fanum"
                        />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    android:text="رمز عبور خود را فراموش کرده‌اید؟   "
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textColor="#616161"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/signUpLayout"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="25dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:hint="شماره تلفن"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/button4"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="#4E4A4A"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
                    app:prefixText="+۹۸"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="phone"
                        android:id="@+id/phoneNumbersi"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_fanum"
                        />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:hint="رمز عبور"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:textDirection="ltr"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/button4"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="#4E4A4A"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
                    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:id="@+id/passwordssi"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_fanum"
                        />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:hint="تکرار رمز عبور"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:textDirection="ltr"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/button4"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="#4E4A4A"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
                    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:id="@+id/confirmpasswordssi"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_fanum"
                        />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/signIn"
                android:text="@string/log_In"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:elevation="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_fanum"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/button5"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/pinkColor"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/OTPLayout"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="یا می‌توانید از طریق زیر وارد شوید"
                android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_fanum"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#474646"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/signInOTP"
                android:text="ورود با شماره تلفن همراه"
                android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_fanum"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:elevation="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/button5"
                app:backgroundTint="#0932FF"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/></LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.sepehr1

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.DialogInterface

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

import android.view.View

import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

@SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables", "CutPasteId")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val signIn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.signIn)
    val singUp = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.singUp)
    val logIn = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.logIn)
    val signUpLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.signUpLayout)
    val logInLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.logInLayout)
    val otpLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.OTPLayout)
    val cardView = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.cardView)
    val phoneNumber = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.phoneNumber)
    var username = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.phoneNumber)
    var password = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.passwords)
    singUp.setOnClickListener{
        singUp.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.switch_trcks,null)
        singUp.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.textColor,null))
        logIn.background = null
        signIn.text="ثبت نام"
        cardView.setPadding(0,0,0,30)
        signUpLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        logInLayout.visibility = View.GONE
        logIn.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.pinkColor,null))
        otpLayout.visibility=View.GONE
    }

    logIn.setOnClickListener{
        singUp.background = null
        signIn.text="ورود"
        cardView.setPadding(0,0,0,0)
        singUp.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.pinkColor,null))
        logIn.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.switch_trcks,null)
        signUpLayout.visibility = View.GONE
        logInLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        logIn.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.textColor,null))
        otpLayout.visibility=View.VISIBLE
    }

}
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sepehr1"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.sepehr1'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sepehr1"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

My app does not open in android 8 or 7 but opens in android 12 and I can not find the reason of this problem and make my app compatible with lower android versions! (I have chosen android 7 as the lowest version of my app while creating the project)

compileSDK is 34 and minSdk is 23 (my app still does not work with lower version of minSDK! And also I made another app with these details and it worked in android 7)

Comment: Can you add your AndroidManifest.xml and your build.gradle files ?

Comment: I added both as you wanted

Comment: Can you also add gradle-wrapper.properties ?

Comment: `#Mon Aug 07 12:54:44 IRST 2023
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists`

Comment: What do you mean by does not open?  Does it install?  If it does, when you run it it must be crashing.  Get us the log of the crash.  If it doesn't install, get us the reason why from adb

Comment: Just tested your configuration in an emulator and my app starts without problems so it must be something else. Is there any type of error in the console / logcat ?

Comment: it installs without problem but when I click on that it says the app stopped

Comment: There is gonna be an error displayed on the logcat of Android Studio which will tell us the cause of "crash"/ANS.

Comment: can you explain more what should I do?

Comment: @AmirElahi there is a window called "Logcat". It simply is a console where Android reports debug informations like warnings and errors. When you open the app and it crashes it should report what's went wrong. (See https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat for more information)

Comment: I saw the error:
`FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.sepehr1, PID: 31064
                                                                                                    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 752277792 byte allocation with 16766368 free bytes and 413MB until OOM at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)`
I saw also the solutions below but they did not work
`android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"` in Manifest